# Compare String array elements to literals Strings

Tags: java

What am I doing wrong in here:

```
public void processFinish(String[] result)
{
    System.out.println(result[0]);
    System.out.println(result[1]);
    System.out.println(result[2]);

    if(result[0] == "true")
        comments.setText("Success");
    else if (result[1] == "true" && result[2] == "false")
        comments.setText("Username is already used");
    else
        comments.setText("Phone number is already used");
}
```

The output is:
true
false
false

Yet, it always executes the else clause !!!

Comment: Sorry.. Stupid question but I'm totally new to programming and Java! Thanks PakkuDon.

Comment: You don't need to apologise for that. It's actually a disturbingly common question under the Java tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this for comparing

```
if(result[0].equals("true"))
        comments.setText("Success");
    else if (result[1].equals("true") && result[2].equals("false"))
        comments.setText("Username is already used");
    else
        comments.setText("Phone number is already used");
```